# How to update multiple rows with pg promise?

Tags: node.js, pg, pg-promise

I want to update multiple rows with pg promise but I don’t understand it fully

Here is my code

I don’t know where I have access to my plan_id

```
    const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(
      ['user_id', 'tenant_id', 'location_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'time_range', 'status', 'info'], { table: 'workers_plan' });

    const cs_values: UpdateWorkersPlan[] = plan.map((el: UpdateWorkersPlan) => ({
      plan_id: el.plan_id,
      user_id: el.user_id,
      tenant_id,
      location_id: el.location_id,
      start_time: el.start_time,
      end_time: el.end_time,
      time_range: tsrange(el.start_time, el.end_time),
      status: el.status,
      info: el.info,
    }));

    pgp.as.format('WHERE plan_id = $1', [how to access plan id ?])

    await pgp.helpers.update(cs_values, cs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the conditional column, defined either as `?plan_id` or as `{name: 'plan_id', cnd: true}`, and append `WHERE` clause that uses that column. See [update](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) for examples.

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(
  [
     '?plan_id',
     'user_id',
     'tenant_id',
     'location_id',
     'start_time',
     'end_time',
     {
         name: 'time_range',
         mod: ':raw',
         init(c) {
             return pgp.as.format('tsrange(${start_time}, ${end_time})', c.source);
         }
     }
     'status',
     'info'
], { table: 'workers_plan' });

const query = pgp.helpers.update(plan, cs) + ' WHERE v.plan_id = t.plan_id';

await db.none(query);
```

And you do not need to remap data, as shown here, use the `plan` array directly, as `ColumnSet` is better and more flexible at remapping data.

Answer (score -1):

With my experience, to **update multiple rows with pg-promise**, you can utilize `pgp.helpers.update` method.

So you should include `plan_id` in `ColumnSet` definition and map it in `cs_values`:

*(haven't tested this code)*

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(
  ['plan_id', 'user_id', 'tenant_id', 'location_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'time_range', 'status', 'info'], { table: 'workers_plan' });

const cs_values = plan.map((el) => ({
  plan_id: el.plan_id,
  user_id: el.user_id,
  tenant_id,
  location_id: el.location_id,
  start_time: el.start_time,
  end_time: el.end_time,
  time_range: tsrange(el.start_time, el.end_time),
  status: el.status,
  info: el.info,
}));

await pgp.helpers.update(cs_values, cs);
```

Docs: https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html

Comment: He needs to use `plan_id` as a conditional column and then append `WHERE` to the query, of which you are missing both here ;) Also, `helpers.update` generates a query, it does not execute anything, so it is completely invalid, I'm afraid.